# Intializing class member variables in constructor

Tags: c++

I recently started working on C++, I observed one strange behaviour while initializing the member variables through the initializer list.

```
//Demo.h
#ifndef DEMO
#define DEMO
#include <iostream>
class Demo
{
public:
    Demo();
    explicit Demo(int x);
};

#endif 

//Demo.cpp
#include "Demo.h"
Demo::Demo()
{
    std::cout << "Demo()" << std::endl;
}
Demo::Demo(int x)
{
    std::cout << "Demo(int x)" << std::endl;
}

//Test.cpp
#include "Demo.h"
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    // : d_(123)
    {
    }

private:
    Demo d_;
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Test t;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code snippet, I created one object for class Demo(`d_`), when I run the program `Demo()` is printing. But if I uncomment the commented code(`d_(123)`) I am getting `Demo(int x)` as output.

The first scenario is clear to me, but the second one I am not able to understand?
*Edit:*
My question is I already created an object(member variables In-class Test), but again I am passing the integer argument in the initializer list. So is it ok to pass, because the object already created and again trying to initialize it?

Comment: I don’t see anything unexpected here, or a concrete question. In what way does the behavior surprise you? What would you expect to happen, and why?

Comment: What do you expect to be surprised by that?

Comment: `Demo` has two constructors, one with no parameters, one that takes an `int`. In `Test` you construct a `Demo` object, using the one that takes an `int`. Thus, the print `Demo(int x)`.

Comment: @rawrex, I already created an object(member variables In-class Test), but again I am passing the integer argument in the initializer list. So is it ok to pass, because the object already created and again trying to initialize?

Comment: *"I already created an object(member variables In-class Test)"* -- no, you did not. Data members do not exist as objects until the class is instantiated.

Comment: @rawrex, Actually I have the class declaration in a header file and definition in the source file(.cpp), I simplified and posted the question.

Comment: @goodman that does not change anything for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **do not initialize** a data member when you just declare it in the body of the class. Actually you do not create anything at all when you write a definition for the class, it is **just a blueprint** for creation of future instances of the class. Later, when you make an object of the class type, the object is created by means of an according constructor, and it is only then we have initialization of the data members.

After you've defined the class, you instantiate it as in

```
Test t; // an object created, default constructor is used
```

In this case, there's an object `t` created, using the default constructor of the `Test`. This default constructor initializes class' data member `d_` of type `Demo` using `Demo`'s constructor that takes an `int`.

When you construct an object, all data members in the member initializer list are **still to be instantiated** *(they aren't default constructed, they are still to be constructed in some way)*. That's the beauty of the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

So, an object can be default constructed, but it can be constructed using other constructor *(non-default)*, in which case the default constructor is not even touched.

*Note, if you were to avoid the use of the member initializer list and initialed data members in the body of the constructor, data members would have been default constructed first, and then reassigned with new values (in the body of the constructor)*.

Comment: Thnx for the explanation. you mentioned object created using default constructor for class Test, I understood this point, but I am doing the same for class Demo, I created an object(`Demo d_`), and again I am trying to pass the integer value to the object through initializer list.

Comment: @goodman you missing the crucial point. You do not create an object in the `private` part of your class. You just saying: *"This class will contain such data member"*.

Comment: I tried your answer and removed the member initializer list and added this in the body of the constructor(`d_ = Demo(123)`). Now I can able to see the invocation of both constructors. Now I am clear, I think I need to understand member initializers more.

Comment: @goodman note that you should use member initializer list for all what is possible, the body is for the rest.

Comment: "This class will contain such data member", yes, so the data member initialization we can provide in the constructor or in some member methods like `init method. If I forgot to initialize the data member then it assumes that the data member is initialized with the default constructor?

Comment: @goodman Yes, we provide needed information using constructors, there are no other `init` methods alike constructor. You can mutate an object using some function. But you can't use some named (member) function for implicit object construction. If some data member is left of the init.list (and has no initializer in the class' body), it will be default constructed. *Note, in such case, built-in types are not initialized at all.*

Comment: Thanx for the detailed information.Now I understood

Answer (score 0):

> The first scenario is clear to me, but the second one I am not able to understand?

In case you uncomment the member initialiser list, you are passing an argument to the constructor of `Demo`.